# Count occurrences depending on column

Tags: r

I have input data in the below format

```
val cond
 1   A
 1   B
 4   C
 1   A
 2   A 
 1   B
```

I want to get output as

```
 val cond occ
 1   A    2 #1 occurs twice for A
 1   B    2 #1 occurs twice for B
 4   C    1 #4 occurs once for C
 1   A    2 #1 occurs twice for A
 2   A    1 #2 occurs once for A
 1   B    2 #1 occurs twice for B
```

What this does is it counts how often a value(first column) occurs for a value in the second column. There must be a function which can do this but I must have been searching the wrong way.
I'm looking for a way to avoid loops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**base R** You can use `ave`

```
df$occ <- ave(seq(nrow(df)), df$val, df$cond, FUN = length)
```

The first argument to `ave` is a vector and the last argument (named `FUN`) is applied to subsets of that vector. The subsets are determined by grouping variables (the intervening unnamed arguments, `df$val` and `df$cond`).

The vector used here `seq(nrow(df))` is just a counter, like `1..nrow(df)` (in pseudocode).

---

**data.table** This is the other convenient package for this, besides `dplyr` (in @aosmith's answer):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[ , occ := .N, by=.(val, cond)]
```

Hopefully, the syntax is transparent. `.N` is a special variable for the number of rows in a subset.

Comment: I picked the ave-solution because it doesn't use a package and it is well readable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If `dat` was the name of your dataset, you could use package *dplyr* for this.  Something like:

```
library(dplyr)

dat = dat %>% 
    group_by(val, cond) %>% 
    mutate(occ = n())
dat

Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
Groups: val, cond

  val cond occ
1   1    A   2
2   1    B   2
3   4    C   1
4   1    A   2
5   2    A   1
6   1    B   2
```